Hierarchical logistic regression interaction
looking for some guidance on analyses.
I'm running hierarchical logistic regression models with a cross-level interaction, x and z (both variables are continuous).
Even though the interaction is not significant, I'd like to compare three groups of z (-1 sd, mean, and +1 sd) across the range of values for x since interactions can be difficult to detect in these models. I have my results and graphed the interaction on my own. Then I graphed it using HLM's graphing tool and it is the same as mine, so all set there. It looks like there might be some sig. differences between the 3 groups when x is high.
My question is, how do I compare these groups? For each level 2 z "group" I have the coef, exp(b) and probability of y across levels of x. How can I see if there are significant differences at "high" x between the groups? I am using HLM and can't really use any other program due to the nature of the data and analyses (36 waves per person, 700 people, 20,000+ data points, missing data, etc.). HLM does not have options for margins like Stata. How should I go about this?
Thank you for any guidance!

Besides the coefficients for x and z and their interaction, your HLM software presumably can return the corresponding variance-covariance matrix. (It might not be returned by default, but should be hiding somewhere within the results of the model.) You want to keep those in the original log-odds scale rather than transforming to odds ratios or probabilities.
You can then perform comparisons on combinations of x and z values by following the formula for the variance of a weighted sum of correlated variables:
$$\operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_{i}^n a_iX_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^na_i^2 \operatorname{Var}(X_i) + 2\sum_{1\le i}\sum_{<j\le n}a_ia_j\operatorname{Cov}(X_i,X_j).$$
In that formula, the $X_i$ are the coefficients for x and for z and for their product (interaction); the (co)variances come from the variance-covariance matrix. The $a_i$ are the corresponding values (or differences in values) at which you want to make the comparison. As the coefficients (in the log-odds scale) are assumed to be have a multivariate normal distribution, you evaluate the difference from 0 of the final estimate of the linear combination by using the variance of the (normal) distribution of that estimate provided by the formula.
There are a couple of dangers in what you want to do, however. If you are trying to focus on "high" x after seeing the results, the p-values wouldn't be reliable as you would be using the results of the model to decide what test to perform. Also, if you are making more than one comparison of this type then you need to adjust for the multiple comparison problem.
You should know that this probably could be done directly in R, whose nlme or lme4 packages should be able to do the fitting, while the emmeans package is designed to provide the marginal means and contrasts that you seek (with proper handling of multiple comparisons. You might even be able to use the coefficient estimates and the variance-covariance matrix from your HLM model to trick emmeans into thinking that your results came from an R package and have it do the calculations for you. As the code is open source, you could at least inspect the code to verify how those calculations are done.
